# Editors can't see /var/www folder

Tags: command-line, permissions, directory, webserver, ide

I put a small web project on local apache from /var/www/html.
It's working from browser and I can see all folders and subfolders from terminal.

But editors (like Atom or Visual Studio Code) can't see www folder from /var.

I changed (from terminal) recursive permissions in 777. But it didn't help.

What else can I do? Can you please help me?

Comment: "I changed (from terminal) recursive permissions in 777"  why? you REALLY need to revert that change. The most I would accept would be for dirs 755 and files 644. If a DIR is not visible is has nothing to do with permissions, Those are always shown and give a "permission denied" if someone is not allowed to go into it.

Comment: I changed permissions in 777 to see if that's the reason I can't see the folder from editor. And I also changed the owner in my user. But didn't help.

Comment: chmod 777 is -never- a solution.

Comment: I understand @Rinzwind. Do you have any idea which is the solution?

Comment: grasping at straws: maybe atom and studio show you a project and not the directory?

Comment: No. It's about opening a folder. They see other folders, but not this one: /www.

Comment: Does this help: https://discuss.atom.io/t/atom-cannot-open-var-www-folder/57176/5 ?